# How can I modify this to work for 2 different modal popups?

Tags: javascript

I have code for one modal and i understand I do not have to duplicate it to allow for another button on the page to call up different content, but I have tried to modify this in multiple ways with no luck.

Please take a look and tell me what i'm missing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    var radios = document.querySelectorAll("#modal input[type='radio']");
    var fields = document.getElementById("modal").querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
    var button_div = document.getElementById("button-div");
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#button-div button");
    document.getElementById("editme").onclick = function() {
        modal.style.visibility = "visible";
        for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { radios[i].classList.add("show"); }
    };
    document.getElementById("close-button").onclick = function () {
        modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
        for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { radios[i].classList.remove("show"); }
    };
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){ fields[i].style.width = fields[i].clientWidth - 18 + "px"; }
    var max = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){ max = ( max > buttons[i].clientWidth ? max : buttons[i].clientWidth ); }
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){ buttons[i].style.width = max + "px"; }
    button_div.style.bottom = button_div.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - modal.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + 40 + "px";

</script>
```

Comment: Kudos for using plain JavaScript. Next, have you tried to simply abstract your snippet into a function (taking the content as an argument) and call that function when clicking one of your buttons instead?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't, but I kind of figured I would have to go that route.

Comment: Indeed, it would seem most clean to me if you take out the code that is responsible for rendering your modal, wrap that in a function and put the modal content as an argument. Then simply attach the click handler you already have set to each button, and make it execute your modal function. Give it a go, and if you run stuck, hop back over to here and edit your question with what you have tried.